# GeneXus: populating grid without base table

Tags: genexus

I´m trying to populate a grid without a base table.

Event `Load` seems not to work for the grid. Code goes as follows:

```
Event gvRelacionProcesos.Load
    for each
        where vRelacionesProcesosItemCode = &pProducto
        where vRelacionesProcesosCustomerCode = &pCliente   
        &vRelacionesProcesosItemCode = vRelacionesProcesosItemCode
        &vRelacionesProcesosCustomerCode = vRelacionesProcesosCustomerCode
        ...
    endfor
EndEvent
```

But it doesn't load, tried some msg() but they don't show either.

Comment: That's all there is in the `Load` event? Are you missing the `Load` command?

Answer (score 0):

There is some code missing in your example, so I'm not sure this is the problem, but you may be missing the `Load` command inside the loop.

```
Event gvRelacionProcesos.Load
    for each
        where vRelacionesProcesosItemCode = &pProducto
        where vRelacionesProcesosCustomerCode = &pCliente   

        &vRelacionesProcesosItemCode = vRelacionesProcesosItemCode
        &vRelacionesProcesosCustomerCode = vRelacionesProcesosCustomerCode
        ...
        Load    \\ This line may be missing
    endfor
EndEvent
```

Answer (score 0):

just found the problem.

I had to 
for each
        where vRelacionesProcesosItemCode = &pProducto
        where vRelacionesProcesosCustomerCode = &pCliente

```
    &vRelacionesProcesosItemCode = vRelacionesProcesosItemCode
    &vRelacionesProcesosCustomerCode = vRelacionesProcesosCustomerCode
    ...
    Load    \\ this loads to the grid, goes to mygrid1.load
```

on event load

then the load event of the grid  (mygrid1.load) happened properly.

thanks anyway.